# How to write a complex filter in tomcat web.xml to accept partially a URL?

Tags: tomcat, filter

I am new to tomcat and I need to filter the URLs on a server to accept all clients for some URLs and accept only a specific IP for other URLs.

In details, I want to accept ALL clients for for this wlidcard URL:

/abc/def/xyz*

and I want to accept only a specific ip for all other wildcard URL:

/abc/def/*

I tried to add the following lines in web.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>Accept all</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>allow</param-name>
    <param-value>.*</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Accept all</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/abc/def/xyz*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
  <filter-name>Accept OnlyMe</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>allow</param-name>
    <param-value>64.64.64.64</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Accept OnlyMe</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/abc/def/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This blocks only /abc/def/* as it should but does not allow everyone to access /abc/def/xyz*

Is there a way to do what I am tryng to do ?

Thank you

Gilbert

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT specify the "allow" parameter in the "Accept all" filter.

> If this attribute is not specified, all requests will be accepted UNLESS the remote address matches a deny pattern.

[Remote_Address_Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_Address_Filter)

Answer (score 0):

That did not work.

When I dont specify the "allow" parameter, I get the same result ( blocking /abc/def/* but nobody can see /abc/def/xyz*).

In my search, I found 2 things :

(1) my url-pattern xyz* is not supported by tomcat ( [wildcards](https://www.websparrow.org/misc/types-of-url-pattern-supported-by-tomcat) ),
(2) this link explains the order of execution of the filters ( [filter order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086712/servlet-filters-order-of-execution) )

Based on these discoveries, I changed my requirement: I would be happy to let everyone access /abc/def/xyz/*  and block everyone on all other /abc/def/* that dont match /abc/def/xyz* . Basically, accept only a subset of /abc/def/* for everyone.

Given the above 2 links ( wildcards + filter order), I wrote the following filters. In my understanding, the first one (Accept All), should let everyone access /abc/def/xyz/* and the second one should block everyone on all other url /abc/def/* that dont match /abc/def/xyz/*

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>Accept All</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>allow</param-name>
    <param-value>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Accept All</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/abc/def/xyz/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
  <filter-name>Block All</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>deny</param-name>
    <param-value>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Block All</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/abc/def/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

It does not work either. This still blocks all url /abc/def/* (including /abc/def/xyz*) to everyone.

Any suggestion ?